# Paired counts sharing the same value of another field into an adjacency list in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join, adjacency-list

I have a table that looks like this

```
| id | name  |
|  A | Fred  |
|  A | Steve |
|  B | Al    |
|  B | Fred  |
|  B | Jim   |
|  C | Steve |
|  C | Jim   |
```

I'm looking for a query that would aggregate the counts of ids by pairs of names that share the same id for all pairs.

That is, my desired query turns that into:

```
| name1 | name2 | value |
| Al    | Al    |     1 |
| Al    | Jim   |     1 |
| Al    | Fred  |     1 |
| Al    | Steve |     0 |
| Fred  | Fred  |     2 |
| Fred  | Jim   |     1 |
| Fred  | Steve |     1 |
| Jim   | Jim   |     2 |
| Jim   | Steve |     1 |
| Steve | Steve |     2 |
```

If I counted correctly, I think that's right.

Noteworthy:

- self-self are the total count for that name, and
- also AB = BA and isn't repeated.
- 0 where Name1 and Name2 have no ids in common

My two questions are:

1. If I'm trying to google this, what is this kind of operation called?  Is this a crosstab? Some kind of pivot?
2. How do I do it?
3. (Extra credit, not just for all pairs, how would I generalize it to do this for all triples?)

Here is my db-fiddle to start:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXffVUHyhTTBGrJRrvYPrx/0

As:

```sql
create table People (
  id text,
  name text
  );
  
insert into People( 
  id, name) VALUES 
    ('A', 'Fred'),
    ('A', 'Steve'),
    ('B', 'Al'),
    ('B', 'Fred'),
    ('B', 'Jim'),
    ('C', 'Steve'),
    ('C', 'Jim');
   
SELECT  a.name as name1, 
        b.name as name2, 
        count(*) as value
   FROM People a
   JOIN People b on a.id = b.id
   WHERE a.name <= b.name
   group by name1, name2;
```

Unfortunately, this produces:

```
| name1 | name2 | value |
| ----- | ----- | ----- |
| Al    | Al    | 1     |
| Al    | Fred  | 1     |
| Al    | Jim   | 1     |
| Fred  | Fred  | 2     |
| Fred  | Jim   | 1     |
| Fred  | Steve | 1     |
| Jim   | Jim   | 2     |
| Jim   | Steve | 1     |
| Steve | Steve | 2     |
```

Which isn't quite what I'm looking for in that it's missing zeros.

Comment: Why is Al-Jim == 0? They share id B... Why is Fred-Fred == 2. When it is total count, Fred shares with all other (= 3)

Comment: You're right about Al-Jim, I will correct.  Fred-Fred is only 2 because Fred does not appear in document C, so his total count is only 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=79d47462149df0b14b34cdf2b746c915)

```
SELECT
    p1.name, p2.name,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE p1.id = p2.id)      -- 2
FROM people p1
    LEFT JOIN people p2 ON p1.name <= p2.name  -- 1
GROUP BY p1.name, p2.name
```

1. Self-join to match all names against all others (this is to get a matching row for `Al` to `Steve` as well); To avoid double pairings (AB and BA) the join condition is `<=`
2. Count all occurrences of pairs, but only these where the id matches. If this would have been done in the join condition, this had eliminated the `Al/Steve` pairing, which now appears with `COUNT = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `distinct` names and `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
with all_people as (select distinct name from people) 
select a.name, b.name, count(case when pa.id = pb.id then 1 end)
  from all_people a
  join all_people b on a.name <= b.name
  left join people pa on a.name = pa.name
  left join people pb on b.name = pb.name
group by a.name, b.name
order by a.name
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fXffVUHyhTTBGrJRrvYPrx/0)

Comment: Your solution doesn't show the Al/Steve pairing.

Comment: Actually the link was incorrect. Please check now.